# Build URI for named Nancy routes

Tags: routes, uri, nancy

I am new to Nancy, and trying to build a URI to a named route. It seems the Nancy.Linker nuget package is what I need for this but when I add it to my project, VS gives a warning that it cannot be used with .NET Core 3 (or .NET Core at all).

The Git page of the package (https://github.com/horsdal/Nancy.Linker/) shows it has had no commit since 2016, so it is probably safe to assume it is dead. Someone under one of the issues says that all you need to do is compile the code against .NET Standard but I am not going to do that. A dead project is dead, period.

I just cannot believe that something so basic is missing from the base library. Is there really no way to do that apart from manually extracting route info from NancyModule.Routes?